# Gnome Tweak Tool problems

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I am now using Ubuntu 12.10 and I tried to install Gnome Shel Extension and Gnome Tweak Tool. However, here is my problem :
[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see that my tweak tool does not receive user themes.. When I checked the Ubuntu Software Center, I see that GNOME Shell Extension Preferences and GNOME Shel User Themes has already installed.

So, what is my problem, and how can I fix it ?
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNOME's official way of installing extensions is through https://extensions.gnome.org/ . I advise you to go there and check if your user theme extension is updated to the latest version. If not, you should be able to fix that through the same website.